# how to get id of a node in TinyMCE?

Tags: tinymce

I want to get the id of a node inside TinyMCE.

I searched in the documentation, but could not find this.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, it is important which node you want to get the id from.
If you want to get the if of the parent node of your selection in TinyMCE use

```
tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getNode().id;
```

EDIT: In case you have a single node in your editor you can access this node id using

```
tinymce.activeEditor.getBody().firstChild.id;
```

Comment: Hi Thariama, Thanks for the solution. This gives the exact Id I want, but only after, I select some text inside the editor. I have a single node inside the editor and want to get it's id where user may select or may not select the text inside it. Thanks

Comment: in that case (single node inside the editor) you may use tinymce.activeEditor.getBody().firstChild.id;

Answer (score 0):

let say if you have id as **txtatinyID**

```
 <textarea class="editorHtml" id="txtatinyID"></textarea>
```

so following will return **txtatinyID** in tinyMCE V4

```
$(tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getNode()).closest('body').data('id')
```

So it will find the body of the current active editor and on the base of it will look for body and in it will get the value of data-id.